# Unrecognized selector when setting NSArray property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that returns an array:

```
-(NSArray*)fetchStoresFromContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Store"];

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

If create a new NSArray and call this method like this:

```
NSArray *test = [self fetchStoresFromContext];
```

everything works fine. [test count] returns 6.

I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* stores;
```

if I call `_stores = [self fetchStoresFromContext]` I get the following error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e3c2f0
```

What's going on here? The property is an NSArray and the object is an NSArray as well so why am I having this problem?

Comment: Your `fetchStoresFromContext` seems to return an `NSNumber`, not an `NSArray`.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant I checked into this when I first encountered the error. `NSLog(@"Class name: %@", NSStringFromClass([[self fetchStoresFromContext] class]));` returns `_NSArrayI`

Comment: Set @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* stores;

Comment: @gottlieb I've tried this and get the same error

Comment: Are you getting that error when you call the method?  Or when you make a call on your ivar later?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your code is passing an NSNumber where the called code expects an NSString or some other object that has a length method.

Not clear enough...Is the error thrown when you do [_stores count] ?

If so, try to instantiate your array before counting :

```
_stores = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self fetchStoresFromContext]];
```